# Why does dladm rename-link fail with "invalid argument"?

Tags: networking, solaris

I am running Solaris 11.1 (in a VM) and have two NICs installed.

At a root console, if I type `dladm show-phys`, it lists `net0` and `net1` and some info for each.

I want to name the links more descriptively, as the networking setup in this VM will likely be changed later.  So, at the root console I enter:

```
dladm rename-link net1 sandirect
```

This yields the error:

```
dladm: rename operation failed: invalid argument
```

Why can't I rename the link?

Answer (score 3):

(Just figured this out before submitting the question.)

`sandirect` is not a valid link name.  It is required that links are named with a numeric suffix.  So, for instance, the following will work instead:

```
dladm rename-link net1 sandirect0
```